# Как найти начальное число, которое больше или равно K, где каждое из N гауссовых чисел меньше или равно M?

Tags: java, случайные-числа

Ввод содержит числа K, N, M в одной строке. Нужно вывести первое начальное число, которое больше или равно K, где каждое из N гауссовых чисел меньше или равно M.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int k = scanner.nextInt();
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        int m = scanner.nextInt();


        int number = 0;
        int seed = 0;
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i < 1000; i++){
            Random random = new Random(i);
            count = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
                number = random.nextInt();
                if(number <= m){
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if(count == n){
                seed = i;
                break;
            }
        } 
        System.out.println(seed);
    }
```

Comment: Первый вопрос, что у вас не получается?

Comment: При вводе данных k=0 n=5 m=0, seed должно быть 38, а у меня получается, что seed=4

Comment: А что такое "гауссовы числа"?

Comment: @MBo смотрим [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B_%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0)это комплексные числа, у которых как вещественная, так и мнимая часть — целые числа

Comment: @Dred Это должно быть описано в вопросе, Гаусс и Эйлер много чего напридумывали :) Если Вы правы, то возникает следующий вопрос - как определено такое: "каждое из N гауссовых чисел меньше или равно M."